# Dashboard Deployment Errors

Tags: dashboard

I have a set of 2 reports, their associated 2 report folders, 2 dashboards, associated 2 dashboard folders.

When I try to deploy via Change Set all of these 8 components, I get this error specifically for the 2 dashboards:

> Cannot find a user that matches any of the following usernames:
>   xyz.abc@company.com.changesetcreationsandbox,
>   xyz.abc@company.com.changesetdeploymentsandbox; remove the user from
>   the component being deployed or create a matching user in the
>   destination organization.

I have no idea what is the issue.

I then tried to deploy the 6 components separately and it worked. So the issue seems to be with Dashboards.

I went into Dashboards and also set the Running User as "Run as specified user". Then I created a separate Change Set for these 2 dashboard items and tried to validate it in destination sandbox. Still the same error.

Can anyone please advise what is the issue and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure the user exists with the same name in production? For example user@example.com is not the same as user@example.com.sandbox

Comment: Pepe, I do not think the same user should exist in sandbox B. I have deployed Change Sets for Dashboard items created in Sandbox A with different username and deployed in Sandbox B. Each sandbox need to have different username. So I don't know why this issue came up today.

Comment: I am having the same issue deploying a change set from one sandbox to another with Summer 13. I have received a similar error when trying to deploy a dashboard and an outbound message, so it is not strictly dashboard-related. I have logged a case with Salesforce and but they do not yet have an answer for me.

Comment: Since by definition Usernames must be unique, it seems contradictory to expect "Workflow Outbound Messages" -- which has User as a required field -- to be able to be deployed between Sandboxes and requiring Usernames to be identical. The deployment will NEVER succeed. Seems that Salesforce should check the email tied to the Username (rather than the Username) which can be identical across multiple instances.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the "run as specific user" completely from the dashboard prior to deployment (set the options to "Run as logged-in user"). Deploy, then change it back to whatever you need.

It tries to find an user by username (in XML of the dashboard definition the reference is stored by username, not by User Id or email). And obviously fails because in production you don't have same sandbox suffix. Same happens when you try to deploy a report/dashboard that's scheduled to be sent to some users or when email alert (from workflows) is being deployed...

Easiest fix is to remove these settings, deploy the "core" of dashboard and amend it manually in the target org.

Alternatively you can temporarily change the username in your target org to be same as the sandbox username (it shouldn't cause login conflicts because the endpoint will still be either login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com)... but I believe you'll hit the lockdown of allowed domain names in your production

Comment: Hello Eyescream, it still fails. Tried to have both dashboards run as logged in user and then created change set for only these 2 dashboards. When I validate it, I still get same error.

Comment: Open up their XML in the target org (it'll be a link in the "line items" of uploaded changeset) and check contents for occurrence of the username?

Comment: I found this line in the xml : <runningUser>vimal.desai@xyz.com.sourcesandboxname</runningUser>.

Comment: Even after setting their type to "LoggedInUser"? Weird, it shouldn't be present in the XML! You might want to raise a Case with SF support. Only solution I can think of for now is to use Eclipse IDE for deployment, you'll be able to edit the XML and put username with working suffix there :(

Comment: I got this information from Salesforce Help : In Summer 13 release Salesforce matches users from your development environment (such as a sandbox) to your production organization. If a component in a deployment refers to a user, such as a recipient of workflow email notifications or a dashboard running user, then Salesforce attempts to locate a matching user in the destination organization by comparing usernames. Previously, a change set deployment changed all user references with the user performing the deployment.

Comment: No idea, how can I toggle this feature to not refer users from source environment.

Comment: But if you have same username in both environments (except the sandbox suffix) and your account is active then it should work OK. I really think this might be a Case to fill with SF support or to put on https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index

Comment: yep, I have raised a case with them. Let us see what they advise. I will keep this post updated with their response. Thanks eyescream.

Comment: It worked for me,when i updated username in source with whatever username is in target(ignoring the .<targetsandboxname>)