# Salesforce promotion

Tags: deployment

There are a few things, like sites, that have settings that contain a sandbox specific user name that blocks promotion of the object into another sandbox/org. Is there any way around this. It would be nice to not have to manually create the site because the user name won't promote. Also, when I set the permissions for a site, it would be nice to have them promote as well.

Is there a way to work around these things or a better way to promote them than using Eclipse? Especially since support for Eclipse is rumored to be waning.

Comment: They've tried to make the process of finding references in workflow emails, dashboard recipients etc bit smarter in Summer '13 but so far I'm kind of disappointed. Please check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/dashboard-deployment-errors?

Answer (score 3):

Sort of. There are a few annoyances with the metadata API that makes things like this a pain.

Specifically for the problem you've described -- deploying a Site record that has a named user in the metadata who doesn't exist in the destination environment -- I've done deployments where we use the Ant Force.com Migration Toolkit to retrieve the metadata, then a sed-type script to edit the user name to the right value, and then deploy it to the target environment.

IMO, using Ant scripts is a better means of deployment than Eclipse. Eclipse leaves a little more room for human error than I like in production deployments, and isn't as scriptable as an Ant-based deployment.